# fun-hooks: referenced 'registerAdserver' but it was never created

Tags: console, advertisement-server, google-chrome-console

I am using adinplay and their advertisement library in [my site](http://colonist.io/).

[image]

It is creating noise in my console. Can I fix this problem? If not what can I do about this log?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @ItayGanor nope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by prebid.js an open-source header bidding library. Prebid is built with multiple optional modules using gulp. This warning is thrown because one of the modules in your build of prebid.js includes a module referencing the hook, but the module that defines the hook is not. Nothing to worry